# How can Websphere PUMA SPI (PumaLocator) be used with an ICEfaces Portlet?

Tags: icefaces, websphere-portal

**Symptoms:**
`PumaLocator` is unusable, every `findXXX`-method returns empty results or throws an exception because nothing was found.

**Analysis:**
The problem seems that, due to the ICEfaces specific architecture, the method `GenericPortlet.doView` is invoked only for the first time the Portlet is loaded, and not for the following (AJAX) page updates, e.g. in case of a called ActionListener.
If I use `PumaLocator` inside the doView-method, everything works fine.

I tried the following attempts yet:

- Get the `PumaLocator` in `doView`, put it into Session and use it later - didn't work
- Get the `RenderRequest` in `doView`, put it into Session and use it later to get a `PumaLocator` by passing that request - didn't work

I would be very glad to have any hints. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PUMA checks the authorization for results by using information found in the Context. You must add JavaEE security roles in the deployment descriptor for the AJAX backend servlets the ICEFaces uses. As a thumb of rule if request.getRemoteUser() and request.getUserPrincipal() return something besides null you know PUMA will work. Otherwise it will **NOT** work and that is intended behaviour.

Alternatively you can attempt to disable the security checks of PUMA [like this.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK56099)

Comment: Thank you for your response - very helpful. Could you please add some more information on exactly what security roles to add? Thanks!

Comment: @Mulmoth Any. Just make sure your servlet (or whatever) requires some authenticated user and role. It doesn't matter what.